# Require two arguments or neither using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), I'd like to be able to have two separate but co-requisite (and otherwise optional) options.

This is similar to [Python argparse: Require two corequisite positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598489/python-argparse-require-two-corequisite-positional-arguments), however the solution suggested there doesn't work for me because I want the options to be separate and named.

I want the usage to look a bit like this:

```
foo.py [-h] [--username USER --password PASS] OTHER_ARGS
```

I want the user to be able to either provide both the `--username` and `--password` options, or neither, but to receive an error if they only pass one.

Comment: While your suggestion is clearer, an alternative is to use one option that requires two arguments (user and pass), e.g. `--login USERNAME PASSWORD`.

Comment: Or, simply process after parsing. e.g `if (args.user and not args.pass) or (args.pass and not args.user):`

Comment: What @Tomerikoo says is correct, but for a more concise code, you can do `if bool(args.user) != bool(args.pass):`